# PHP & SQL: requests to mysql updates without refresh page

Tags: php, sql

I have an img with a link of a request next every reply in one post. and it allow the author of the post to select the right answer. if you clicked on the img it will do a request...

the request will update the reply to be `the right answer` reply (* similar to stackoverflow.com)

the problem is when I do that, it always send me to the top of the page. I think it refreshs.
I want to avoid refreshing or sending me to the top of the page. I want it to do nothing but the request.

some people told me the solution is javascript. but how ? because I can't with javascript do requests nor sql updates ... ?

Comment: google for `"ajax php javascript"`

Comment: maybe the image is in an `a` tag and the tag has the `href` attribute set to `#` so it will jump to the top. Just remove the `a` and it will be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can make requests to the server without refreshing the page.  Usually, a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is used to make the process easier.

In your example, JavaScript needs to do two things:

1. Tell the server (php/mysql) what answer was selected as correct so that future visitors see the change
2. Update the client (browser) to show the change.

That should be enough to get you started - you are going to need to learn quite a bit.  Read the docs at jquery.com and search for code examples.